# How to read MultipartContent from HttpResponseMessage?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have the following WebApi which returns MultipartContent to the client containing an image from a database and a bit of additional data:-

```
    public class PhotoController : ApiController
{

    public HttpResponseMessage GetPhoto(Int32 personId)
    {
        var service = new PhotoService();
        var photo = service.SelectPrimaryPhoto(personId);
        if (photo == null)
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        var content = new MultipartContent();
        content.Add(new ObjectContent<Photo.Data>(photo, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()));
        content.Add(new StreamContent(photo.Image));
        response.Content = content;
        return response;
    }
}
```

On the client, the HttpResponseMessage.Content is surfaced as type StreamContent.  How can I access it as MultipartContent?  The client is WPF - not a Web Browser.

Comment: Not really.  I wasn't expecting that I'd need to implement my own MediaTypeFormatter for 'multipart/mixed'.  One can easily deal with MultipartContent in an HttpRequestMessage so the formatter must be there.  It's just not obvious how to read multipart content on the client.

Comment: Or perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/q/12413287/56778? See the comments in the accepted answer for a link to some examples.

Comment: Thanks Jim.  I've been through all the likely looking WebApi samples and spent a long time searching the internet but haven't found anything which deals with reading Multipart on the client.  I wouldn't have thought it was that rare a scenario.

Comment: Have you tried using ReadAsMultipartAsync method? Henrik's blog post has an example of reading content as multipart on the service side accepting request: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/04/27/asp-net-web-api-updates-april-27.aspx

Comment: Kiran, thanks for the link, I'd missed that one though been through many other posts relating to ReadAsMultipartAsync.  My problem was that ReadAsMultipartAsync wasn't showing up on response.Content for some reason so I assumed it wasn't available.  It's there now. :)  I'll have another go in the morning.  Thanks

Answer (score 8):

First you need to add a reference to `System.Net.Http.Formatting`,

then you will have access to the extension method `.ReadAsMultipartAsync()`.

**Example**:

```
using System.Net.Http.Formatting;

// ...

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsyc("{send the request to api}");

var content = await response.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();

var stringContent = await content.Contents[0].ReadAsStringAsync();
var streamContent = await content.Contents[1].ReadAsStreamAsync();
```

Comment: Quick comment for those finding this from Google: `ReadAsMultipartAsync` is not available without installing the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` package from NuGet. Also note that this package silently conflicts with `Microsoft.Net.Http` when using this method, so remove that package first.

Comment: Of note, there is a System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension package that seems to work, but is not from Microsoft and is .NET Framework 4

Answer (score 0):

You can use the helper methods in [HttpContentMultipartExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh835439%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) to read the content on the client side.